# EventAggregator alternative

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been trying to use this version of an EventAggregator [here](https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.EventAggregator/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue)

I have been using it in a Blazor Server app which is a rewrite of an Old Silverlight app which used an EventAggregator.  However, I have had many issues with it.  The latest of which it doesn't fire the events when it should (have no idea why it is not working correctly).

In any case, I am looking for an alternative pattern.

What I am looking for is a way to tell multiple components that the "CurrentCustomer" has changed, so that the components can update themselves.

Is there a recommended pattern or way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like SignalR, here is a tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

Answer (score 1):

This is the only EventAggregator for Blazor that I have found: [https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/blazor-eventaggregator-2-0-0-auto-refresh](https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.EventAggregator)

The only thing worthy of note is that the current default is the following:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<EventAggregator.Blazor.IEventAggregator, EventAggregator.Blazor.EventAggregator>();//Use this.
//builder.Services.AddEventAggregator(); Not this. It adds it as a singleton which is NOT what we want. Change requested of author. The Events will be propagated to every user everywhere, instead of just the current user.
```

Answer (score 1):

2 years later, and I now use a different approach than trying to fire and catch events. Events have caused memory issues and doesn't really work in a component based environment like Blazor Server.

Instead of using events, I use the built in Cascading Parameters to flow parameters down to all components which need them.

So, for example, if you have a Cascading Parameter of CurrentCustomer, it will propagate this down the hierarchy of components.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best thing I have found is the StateContainer as described: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server)  It's just a simple class that holds state, and you can subscribe to it's events.